# git error cannot handle Commit as a builtin

Tags: git, git-commit

I tried this command

> $ git Commit -m  "With ViewPager"

and getting this error

> fatal: cannot handle Commit as a builtin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `commit` instead of `Commit` :)

Answer (score 5):

This error will also occur for other functions such as:

```
GIT STATUS
GIT ADD
GIT COMMIT
GIT PUSH
```

Always use lower case lettering for commands.

Comment: Probably because Git must function in *nix system where commands are more case sensitive than on Windows OS-es ? The limitation sounds a bit unecessary on Windows ? Perhaps redirecting it as an aliased command should help ?

Comment: I don't think you need to lowercase git, at least on my MacOS

Answer (score 1):

I mean the solution is always smallcase, as its case sensitive.

1. git status
2. git add
3. git commit
4. git push

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error for `CLONE`, fixed it by changing to `clone`

Answer (score 0):

Also it appears when you use any of the character as capital, eg: Commit
It's Case sensitive
solution is

1. git status
2. git add
3. git commit
4. git push

Comment: This should be a comment. Please only post an answer if you have an actual solution

Answer (score 0):

git command consider case sensitivity (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops).

so use snake case command "commit".